# Error message when try to run a function in function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I create two functions that worked well as a stand alone functions.
But when I try to run one of them inside the second one I got an error:
**'SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated'**

Can you advise?
Adding code bellow:

```
CASE  
    WHEN (regexp_substr(ARGUMENTS_JSON,'drives_removed":\\[]') = 'drives_removed":[]') THEN **priceperitem(1998, returnitem_add_item(ARGUMENTS_JSON))**
    WHEN (regexp_substr(ARGUMENTS_JSON,'drives_added":\\[\\]') = 'drives_added":[]') THEN 1
    WHEN (regexp_substr(ARGUMENTS_JSON,'from_flavor') = 'from_flavor') THEN 1
    WHEN (regexp_substr(ARGUMENTS_JSON,'{}') = '{}') THEN 1
    ELSE 'Other'
END as Price_List,
```

The problem happened when with function 'priceperitem'
If I replace returnitem_add_item with a string then it will work fine.

Function 1 : priceperitem get customer number and a item  return  pricing per the item from customer pricing list 
Function 2 : returnitem_add_item parsing string and return a string

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may try processing udf within a udf in the following way :

```
create function x()
returns integer
as
$$
select 1+2
$$
;

set q=x();

create function pi_udf(q integer)
  returns integer
  as 
  $$
  select q*3
  $$
  ;

select pi_udf($q);
```

If this does not work out as well, the issue might be data specific. Try executing the function with one record, and then add more records to see the difference in the behavior. There are certain limitations on using SQL UDF's in Snowflake and hence the 'Unsupported Subquery' Error.